# Displaying specific cards in hand in a Euchre program

Tags: c

I've been trying to work on this for hours now trying different things to get the appropriate result. I'm trying to get the program to print out if it finds a Jack in a hand. It works, but it doesn't.

Output:

*Ace of Diamonds*
*Ace of Hearts*
*Ten of Clubs*
*Queen of Diamonds*
*Nine of Spades*

*A Jack has been found!*

This is what I meant by it works, but doesn't. So, I got it to say "A Jack has been found!" which is good, but it keeps saying it even if there is no Jack in the hand. I tried looking up tips for Euchre in C programming, but can't find anything. I even tried Googling my goal, but nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define SUITS 4
#define FACES 6
#define CARDS 24
//#define HAND 5 

// prototypes

    void shuffle(unsigned int wDeck[][FACES]); // shuffling modifies wDeck
void deal(unsigned int wDeck[][FACES], unsigned int hand[][2], const char                   *wFace[], const char *wSuit[]);
void jack(unsigned int hand[][2], const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[]) ;

//~ void jack_ace(unsigned int wHands[][FACES], unsigned int hand[][2],
        //~ const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[]) ;

int main(void) {
// initialize deck array
unsigned int deck[SUITS][FACES] = {0};
unsigned int hand[5][2];
srand(time(NULL)); // seed the RNG
shuffle(deck); // shuffle the deck

// initialize suit array
const char *suit[SUITS] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};

// initialize face array
const char *face[FACES] = {"Ace", "Nine", "Ten","Jack", "Queen", "King"};

deal(deck, hand, face, suit); // deal the deck
jack(hand, face, suit);
//~ jack_ace(hand, deck, face, suit);
}

// shuffle cards in deck
void shuffle(unsigned int wDeck[][FACES]) {
// for each of the cards, choose slot of deck randomly
for (size_t card = 20; card <= CARDS; card++) {
    size_t row;
    size_t column;

    // choose new random location until unoccupied slot found
    do {
        row = rand() % SUITS;
        column = rand() % FACES;
    } while (wDeck[row][column] != 0);

    // place card number in chosen slot of deck
    wDeck[row][column] = card;
}
}

// deal cards in deck
void deal(unsigned int wDeck[][FACES], unsigned int hand[][2], const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[]) {
// deal each of the cards
for (size_t card = 20; card <= CARDS; card++) {
    // loop through rows of wDeck
    for (size_t row = 0; row < SUITS; row++) {
        // loop through columns of wDeck for current row
        for (size_t column = 0; column < FACES; column++) {
            // if slot contains current card, display card

     // end if
            if (wDeck[row][column] == card) {
                printf("%5s of %-8s%c", 
                        wFace[column], wSuit[row],
                        card % 2 == 0 ? '\n' : '\t');

              } // end if
            } // end column for loop
        } // end row for lop
    } // end card for loop
} // end deal function

void jack(unsigned int hand[][2], const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[]) {
// lets you know that there is a Jack in the hand
unsigned int count[FACES] = {0};
int hold;
for(size_t i = 0; i <= 5; i++){ 
    hold = (hand[i][0]) %5; 
    count[hold] = count[hold] + 1;
for(size_t j = 3; j < FACES; ++j){ 
    if(count[j] == 1){ // assigns value to find the Jack in the hand
        printf("A %4s has been found!\n", wFace[j]);

            }       
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Typically, one would define a structure that represents one card. The structure would contain the rank and suit of the card. Then the deck, and each hand, would be an array of those structures.

Comment: The code is difficult to follow.  You excessively comment things that are unimportant, and don't comment things that are (such as why you modulo by 5, or what `FACES` represents, or why you begin your search at 3, just as example).  These are unintuitive implementation details that only you think are obvious, but to a seasoned developer they make no sense without a detailed examination.  Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger to determine what assumptions you're making are actually valid?

Comment: See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck... Really, it helps `:)`

Comment: @user3386109 We haven't got to structures yet.

Comment: @paddy I did the modulo of 5 considering the hand has 5 cards, and what do you mean "what FACES represets"? Wouldn't it represent Ace, 9, 10 ,J, Q, K? And I begin my search at 3, because that is what the Jack value is, if I put it to 0 it'll say An Ace has been found instead.

Comment: I expect there are more problems but a big one is you never initialise `hand`.  Presumably that's what the deal function is supposed to do. Your code really is not easy to read. If someone told you to write comments like that, please pass on this message from me: "NO!" :)

Comment: That would be my teacher lol

Comment: It's more likely you misinterpreted what they were saying. You should write meaningful comments or none at all. If your comment just describes the language construct being used, that should be a red flag to you. Also, use indentation correctly and _please_ stop putting comments on a `}`!

Comment: Force of habit to put them on } because when I took Java, I was told to do that.

Comment: Btw @paddy quick question if you don't mind. You asked if I used a debugger to determine if the assumptions are valid. What do you mean by that? So far we've went over some of gdb in Linux terminal, is there a function to show if you need something or not?